# The direct limit of a sequence of compact normal spaces is regular

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose $X$ is a topological space equipped with the direct limit topology of the sequence $K_1\subset K_2\subset \cdots$ where each $K_n$ is compact Hausdorff. Thus a set $A\subset X$ is open [resp. closed] iff the intersection $A\cap K_n$ is open [resp. closed] in $K_n$, for each $n$. I am then trying to show that $X$ is itself regular.

Thus I have to show that $X$ is itself Hausdorff, and that if $C$ is a closed subset of $X$ and $x\in X-C$, then there are disjoint open sets $U,V\subset X$ such that $C\subset U$ and $x\in V$. It seems that the proofs of these two states will be similar, but I can't see how to prove these. Any hints?

Comment: Well, for the Hausdorff-ness for instance, you take $x,y$, so you can find an $n$ s.t $x,y$ both are in $K_n$, but $K_n$ is Hausdorff...

Comment: @Ahr Yes in that way we can take open sets $U,V$ in $K_n$, but $U,V$ are not necessarily open in $X$ of course.

Comment: No, indeed, but chosing open $U, V$ whose closure don't intersect, you may "thicken" them to get $U_1, V_1$ in $K_{n+1}$ which are open in $K_{n+1}$ and whose closures don't intersect, and continue this process inductively.

Comment: @Ahr You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we show that the space $X$ is Hausdorff. Let $x,y$ be any distinct points of the space $X$. There exists a natural number $n$ such that $x,y\in K_n$. Since $K_n$ is Hausdorff compact space, it is Tychonoff and so there exists a continuous function $f_n: K_n\to\Bbb R$ such that $f_n(x)\ne f_n(y)$. Since each $K_m$ is a closed subspace of a normal space $K_{m+1}$, we can inductively extend $f_n$ to a continuous function $f_{n+1}$ from $K_{n+1}$ to $\Bbb R$, then to a continuous function $f_{n+2}$ from $K_{n+2}$ to $\Bbb R$ and so forth. Since $X=\bigcup K_m$, there is a function $f:X\to\Bbb R$ such that $f|K_m=f_m$  for each $m\ge n$. Since for each closed subset $F$ of $\Bbb R$ and each $m\ge n$, we have $f^{-1}(F)\cap K_m=f_m^{-1}(F)$, we see that the set $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$. So the map $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

Note that the space $X$ is $k_\omega$. According to [FT], each Hausdorff $k_\omega$-space is normal. A bit stronger fact than regularity of a Hausdorff $k_\omega$-space is proved in our paper [BR], see Proposition 1 and definitions before it.

*References*

[BR] T. Banakh, A. Ravsky, *[On subgroups of saturated or totally bounded paratopological groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5355)*, Algebra and Discrete Mathematics, **4** (2003), 1-–20.

[FT] S.P. Franklin, B.V. Smith Thomas, *A survey of $k_\omega$-spaces*, Topology Proc. **2** (1977), 111–124.

Comment: And [FT] is freely available online [here](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v02/tp02105.pdf); the normality result is at the bottom of p.113. Alternatively, one gets normality for free from regularity, since the space is Lindelöf.